# How to set kik bot webhook

Tags: bots, kik

I am trying to setup my first test bot in kik messanger , tried to set up webhhok using php:
https://api.kik.com/v1/config?botname:token/?webhook=https://example.com
Please advise, how to set up webhook using php url (For Telegram bot such request works fine).

Thank you

Comment: When I set webhook for telegram bot, I just run following https://api.telegram.org/bot<id>:<token>/setWebhook?url=https://example.com  
  and avarything is fine. I would like to do the same for kik bot..

Comment: You need to be making a post request. This has the url and the auth headers you need https://dev.kik.com/#/docs/messaging#configuration

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a POST and not a GET. I used [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/). After setting Basic Auth header with your bot username and API key, then Content-type header to "application/json", I changed the body type to "raw" and just entered in the json data I wanted my config to be:

```
{
  "webhook": [your webhook url here],
  "features": {
    "receiveReadReceipts": false,
    "receiveIsTyping": false,
    "manuallySendReadReceipts": false,
    "receiveDeliveryReceipts": false
  }
}
```

When I sent the request, the response had my config data returned in the response. This also worked when I needed to change one of the config parameters. Hope this helps.